# Is it possible to add CID TTF Names using python script with fontforge library?

Tags: python, fontforge

I really need to add/change the "Preferred Family" and "Preferred Styles" to the TTF Names table into the CID font info meta data.

The following code successfully edits both the standard font info and cid font info, but the name table remains unchanged. I suspect the `appendSFNTName()` method tries to change the TTF Names of the standard font info and not the CID font info. Question is if the fontforge team maybe only implemented the standard font infos and left out the rest of the CID info data, because I can't find much in their documentation.

```
import fontforge
import string
import sys
font = fontforge.open(sys.argv[1])

family_name = sys.argv[2]
style_name = sys.argv[3]

font.familyname = family_name
font.fullname = family_name + " " + style_name
font.fontname = family_name.replace(" ","")+ "-" + style_name
font.weight=style_name
font.cidfamilyname = family_name
font.cidfullname = family_name + " " + style_name
font.cidfontname = family_name.replace(" ","")+ "-" + style_name
font.cidweight=style_name
font.appendSFNTName("English (US)","Preferred Family",family_name)
font.appendSFNTName("English (US)","Preferred Styles",style_name)

font.generate(sys.argv[1].replace(".otf","_edited.otf"), flags=("opentype"))
```